# How to get the current opened stage in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to get the current opened Stage in JavaFX, if there is one open?

Something like this:

```
Stage newStage = new Stage();
newStage.initOwner(JavaFx.getCurrentOpenedStage()); //Like this
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do this. What is the context for this? Perhaps there is another way to do what you want. If this is in response to a user action you can always get the window containing the window containing a node with `node.getScene().getWindow()`.

Comment: The notification shows inside a "infinite" loop inside a thread. In this thread, i don't have the reference to any window, because the thread is started from the first application window (login window) which closes after the user logs into the system, but the thread keeps running.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Java 9 makes this possible by the addition of the `javafx.stage.Window.getWindows()` method. Therefore you can just get list of Windows and see which are showing

```
List<Window> open = Stage.getWindows().stream().filter(Window::isShowing);
```

Comment: `filtered` produces a `FilteredList`. This kind of object is a lot more heavyweight than needed. I recommend iterating through the list or using a stream: `Window owner = Stage.getWindows().stream().filter(Window::isShowing).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Answer (score 18):

If you need the current stage reference inside an event handler method, you can get it from the ActionEvent param. For example:

```
    @FXML
    public void OnButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {

        Stage stage = (Stage)((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

       (...)
    }
```

You can also get it from any control declared in your controller:

```
@FXML
private Button buttonSave;

(...)    

Stage stage = (Stage) buttonSave.getScene().getWindow();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but please can you explain why did you get the window and then convert it into a scene rather than the scene from the source ?

Comment: Actually I didn't do that. Notice that I got the scene, and then I got the window from the scene.

Comment: very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

There's no built-in functionality for this. In most use cases, you open a new `Stage` as a result of user action, so you can call `getScene().getWindow()` on the node on which the action occurred to get the "current" window.

In other use cases, you will have to write code to track current windows yourself. Of course, multiple windows might be open, so you need to track them in some kind of collection. I'd recommend creating a factory class to manage the stages and registering event handlers for the stages opening and closing, so you can update a property and/or list. You'd probably want this to be a singleton. Here's a sample implementation: here `getOpenStages()` gives an observable list of open stages - the last one is the most recently opened - and `currentStageProperty()` gives the focused stage (if any). Your exact implementation might be different, depending on your exact needs.

```
public enum StageFactory {
    INSTANCE ;

    private final ObservableList<Stage> openStages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Stage> getOpenStages() {
        return openStages ;
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<Stage> currentStage = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
    public final ObjectProperty<Stage> currentStageProperty() {
        return this.currentStage;
    }
    public final javafx.stage.Stage getCurrentStage() {
        return this.currentStageProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setCurrentStage(final javafx.stage.Stage currentStage) {
        this.currentStageProperty().set(currentStage);
    }

    public void registerStage(Stage stage) {
        stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, e -> 
                openStages.add(stage));
        stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN, e -> 
                openStages.remove(stage));
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (isNowFocused) {
                currentStage.set(stage);
            } else {
                currentStage.set(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public Stage createStage() {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        registerStage(stage);
        return stage ;
    }

}
```

Note this only allows you to track stages obtained from `StageFactory.INSTANCE.createStage()` or created elsewhere and passed to the `StageFactory.INSTANCE.registerStage(...)` method, so your code has to collaborate with that requirement. On the other hand, it gives you the chance to centralize code that initializes your stages, which may be otherwise beneficial.

Here's a simple example using this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class SceneTrackingExample extends Application {

    int count = 0 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StageFactory factory = StageFactory.INSTANCE ;
        factory.registerStage(primaryStage);

        configureStage(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void configureStage(Stage stage) {
        StageFactory stageFactory = StageFactory.INSTANCE;
        Stage owner = stageFactory.getCurrentStage() ;
        Label ownerLabel = new Label();
        if (owner == null) {
            ownerLabel.setText("No owner");
        } else {
            ownerLabel.setText("Owner: "+owner.getTitle());
            stage.initOwner(owner);
        }
        stage.setTitle("Stage "+(++count));
        Button newStage = new Button("New Stage");
        newStage.setOnAction(e -> {
            Stage s = stageFactory.createStage();
            Stage current = stageFactory.getCurrentStage() ;
            if (current != null) {
                s.setX(current.getX() + 20);
                s.setY(current.getY() + 20);
            }
            configureStage(s);
            s.show();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, ownerLabel, newStage);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 360, 150));
    }

    public enum StageFactory {
        INSTANCE ;

        private final ObservableList<Stage> openStages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public ObservableList<Stage> getOpenStages() {
            return openStages ;
        }

        private final ObjectProperty<Stage> currentStage = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
        public final ObjectProperty<Stage> currentStageProperty() {
            return this.currentStage;
        }
        public final javafx.stage.Stage getCurrentStage() {
            return this.currentStageProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setCurrentStage(final javafx.stage.Stage currentStage) {
            this.currentStageProperty().set(currentStage);
        }

        public void registerStage(Stage stage) {
            stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, e -> 
                    openStages.add(stage));
            stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN, e -> 
                    openStages.remove(stage));
            stage.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (isNowFocused) {
                    currentStage.set(stage);
                } else {
                    currentStage.set(null);
                }
            });
        }

        public Stage createStage() {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            registerStage(stage);
            return stage ;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a label in your java fxml.

Then in your controller class refer your label like this :

`@FXML
 private Label label;`

Then in any function of the controller class you can access the current stage by this block of code :

```
private void any_function(){
        Stage stage;
        stage=(Stage) label.getScene().getWindow();
}
```

Comment: This is like a life-hack and it helped me greatly :)

Comment: very useful, indeed! Thank you!